# How can I testing the Message Dialog/Box from SWT(with SWTBot)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, swt, swtbot

> 

```
Is the message box native SWT? I ask, because SWTBot can't handle native SWT dialogs like message boxes or file dialogs.
Suggestion: work in your application code with (JFace) MessageDialog.openInformation(....) and not nativ SWT dialogs. This works fine with SWTBot.<
```

I can with `MessageDialog.openInformation(....)` create a MessageDialog, but I will testing what happens when I click "Yes" or "No".
I tried to interpreted the "Yes" and "No" Buttons in der MessageDialog as Buttons.

```
okButton = bot.button("Yes");
```

However I  get a  "org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.exceptions.WidgetNotFoundException: Could not find widget."

Who I can test it?

Comment: I recommend use JOptionPane to create a dialog, but I don't know, what is a SWTBot :/

Comment: @barwnikk The question is not about Swing/AWT.

Comment: Make sure the button is not "OK" / "Cancel".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test the native dialog with SWTBot.

Reference: [SWTBot Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/FAQ#How_do_I_use_SWTBot_to_test_native_dialogs_.28File_Dialogs.2C_Color_Dialogs.2C_etc.29.3F)